# Finding a closed form for $f(n)=f(n-1)-9f(n-2)+9f(n-3)+5$ (with complex numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to get a closed form for the non-homogeneous linear recurrence
$$f(n)=f(n-1)-9f(n-2)+9f(n-3)+5$$
The initial values are
$$f(0) = 1,\ f(1) = 1,\ f(2) = 2$$
But I'm having trouble when I found imaginary numbers.

Let's see: I know there are homogeneous linear recurrences associated to this non-homogeneous one, in this case it is $f(n) = f(n-1) - 9f(n-2) + 9f(n-3)$. Its characteristic equation is $x^3-x^2+9x-9 = 0$.

On the other hand, the non-homogeneous part is $1^n\cdot 5$ so, as I've been told, there is a homogeneous linear recurrence that is similar to the first one (non-homogeneous) and that has the characteristic equation $(x-5)(x^3-x^2+9x-9)$ but, when I find the roots of the second polynomial, I get $(x-1)(x^2+9)$ and this second part has no real roots... so...

I don't know if it is correct to write the homogeneous linear recurrence as:
$$f(n) = a + 5^n  b + (3i)^n c + (-3i)^n d$$

Actually, I have no idea of how I should do this problem from this moment onward. Could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Try $f(n)=kn$ to solve for a particular solution.

Comment: ?? I can't understand you. Could you be more explanatory (?)

Comment: What are the values for $f(1), f(2), f(3)$?

Comment: Um.. sorry, I forgot to put it. I've edited. These are: F(0) = 1, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2

Answer (score 1):

You have the characteristic equation
$$x^3 - x^2 + 9x - 9 = 0 \\
\implies (x - 1)(x^2 + 9) = 0 \\
\implies x = 1 \;\; \text{OR} \;\; 3i \;\; \text{OR} \;\; -3i$$
Thus the solutions to the homogeneous part are
$$f(n) = c_1 \cdot 1^n + c_2 \cdot (3i)^n + c_3 \cdot (-3i)^n$$
But we have a constant nonhomogeneous part, which must satisfy the same recurrence relation. Let us guess that the nonhomogeneous solution is of the form $an + b$.
$$an + b = a(n-1) + b - 9(a(n-2) + b) + 9(a(n-3) + b) + 5 \\
\implies 0 = -a + 18a - 27a + 5 \\
\implies -10a = -5 \\
\implies a = \frac{-5}{-10} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Since the $b$ term is absent, $b = 0$. Now we simply have
$$f(n) = c_1(1)^n + c_2(3i)^n + c_3(-3i)^n + \frac{1}{2}n$$
which we solve for $f(0)$, $f(1)$, and $f(2)$:
$$\begin{align*}
f(0) = 1 &= c_1 + c_2 + c_3 \\
f(1) = 1 &= c_1 + 3ic_2 - 3ic_3 + \frac{1}{2} \\
f(2) = 2 &= c_1 - 9c_2 - 9c_3 + 1
\end{align*}$$
to get $c_1 = 1$, $c_2 = \frac{i}{12}$, $c_3 = -\frac{i}{12}$. Finally we have
$$f(n) = 1 + \frac{(3i)^n - (-3i)^n}{12}i + \frac{1}{2}n$$

Answer (score 0):

Using method of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Let us write equation for general term:
$$
f_n=f_{n-1}-9f_{n-2}+9f_{n-3}+5-4[n=0]-5[n=1]+5[n=2]
$$
Make transform to $G(z):$
$$
G=zG-9z^2G+9z^3G+\frac{5}{1-z}-4-5z+5z^2\\
G=\frac{5}{(1-z)(1-z+9z^2-9z^3)}-\frac{4+5z-5z^2}{1-z+9z^2-9z^3}
$$
In form of partial fractions:
$$
G=\frac{36+81z}{10(1+9z^2)}+\frac{9}{10(1-z)}+\frac{1}{2(1-z)^2}-\frac{36+86z}{10(1+9z^2)}-\frac{4}{10(1-z)}\\
G=\frac{-5z}{10(1+9z^2)}+\frac{5}{10(1-z)}+\frac{1}{2(1-z)^2}\\
G=\frac{-z}{2(1+9z^2)}+\frac{1}{2(1-z)}+\frac{1}{2(1-z)^2}
$$

And one more partial fraction for first addendum:
$$
G=\frac{3i}{18}\left[\frac{A}{1+3iz}-\frac{A^*}{1-3iz}\right]+\frac{1}{2(1-z)}+\frac{1}{2(1-z)^2}$$

Where $A=A^*=-\frac{1}{2}$
Now apply inverse transform:
$$
f(n)=\frac{i}{6}A(-3i)^n-\frac{i}{6}A^*(3i)^n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)\\
f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)+\frac{i}{12}(3i)^n-\frac{i}{12}(-3i)^n
$$
As it can be ssen, you had almost proper equation, with only term $(+5)$ mistreated. Reason: we add it, not multiply.
By the way, important property: constants $c$ and $d$ must be self-conjuncted, because $f(n)$ is real-valued sequence.

And finally, let us rewrite expression a bit.
$$
f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)+\frac{i}{12}(3i)^n\left[1-(-1)^n\right]\\
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
1+k,\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{for n=2k} \\
\frac{3}{2}+k-\frac{(-9)^k}{2},\quad \text{for n=2k+1}
\end{cases}
$$